# Periodic automatic partition restoration

Tags: partitioning, automation, restore

I am looking for some freeware / cheap software for restoring/rewriting a partition from an image file (on another partition) automatically once a a day or week.

The OS to be restored is Windows XP. It shall automatically reboot to begin the restoration in some other (maybe linux) OS to do the restoration and then boot back into XP.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only one I have found that is free<sup>**+**</sup> is [Comodo Time Machine](http://www.comodo.com/home/data-storage-encryption/data-recovery.php). A quick glance does not reveal any way to automaticly restore at scheduled times, only on demand or reboot. But that does not mean it does not exist.

> Comodo Time Machine (CTM) is a powerful system rollback utility that allows users to quickly restore their computers to an earlier point in time. CTM 'snapshots' are a complete record of your entire system (including the registry, critical operating system files and user created documents).

#### Features

- Easy to use - even beginners can quickly create system snapshots with a few mouse clicks
- Provides instant and comprehensive system recovery after virus or spyware infections
- Instantly reclaim your machine after devastating system crashes
- Rollback the changes to ALL your documents - not just changes to system files and the registry
- Boot-up console allows you to rollback even when your system will not boot to Windows
- Test new software and network configurations in the knowledge that you can quickly switch back if problems develop
- Completely remove unwanted software installations without the need to uninstall or clean the registry
- Flexible restore options allow you to mount and browse snapshots to recover individual files or folders
- Right click on any file or folder to synchronize it with a snapshot version
- Schedule regular system snapshots to ensure highly relevant restore points
- Network administrators have another way to quickly fix user or software problems
- Libraries, Internet cafes and other publicly shared networks can schedule a total system restore at the end of each session

<sup>**+**</sup>Only free for non commercial use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look this up. Oh yes, the use is commercial! However, if the price is not high, it might not be a problem actually. Also, it might be automatically in the following sens: another program initiates the process, then it restores the partition and **boots back in XP**